# created_at != Date.today for new row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I check if a row was updated today? **updated_at is saying it is Jan 07** and **Date.today is saying it is Jan 06.**

The code below evaluates to false for a few hours a day for a row that was created milliseconds ago.

```
up_votes.where(:post_id => params[:post_id]).order('updated_at DESC').limit(1).first.updated_at.to_date == Date.today
```

Am I correct using Date.today in a controller to compare against active record timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not you just use `today?()` function of the api?  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-today-3F

Answer (score 0):

> created_at is saying it is Jan 07 and Date.today is saying it is Jan
>   06.

I hope it is true because of `Date.today` is not in GMT zone, but created_at is.
Try  `Time.now.utc.to_date` instead of `Date.today`

Also I noticed that you have asked about created_at but used updated_at in your example

Comment: so did you figured out that database records timestamps are stored with utc ?

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that but why doesn't rails take care of that? Timestamps are so common. Why does Time.now not match activerecord in a running rails app?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L102   here is how it works